# Dot density map using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, density

I want to show cluster of point data on map using OpenLayers. I have been following this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html but the problem is that want a look like dot density map like each state has only one dot and dot size varies according to count.

```
var style_ch = new ol.style.Style({
    pointRadius: "${radius}",
    fillColor: "#FF3300",
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeColor: "#66FF00",
    strokeWidth: "${width}",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    label: "${getLabel}",
    fontSize: "12px",
    fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    labelOutlineColor: "white",
    labelOutlineWidth: 2.5
}, {
    context: {
        width: function (feature) {
            return (feature.cluster) ? 2 : 1;
        },
        radius: function (feature) {
            var pix = 2;
            if (feature.cluster) {
                pix = Math.min(feature.attributes.count, 7) + 2;
            }
            return pix;
        },
        getLabel: function (feature) {
            if (feature.cluster) {
                if (feature.cluster.length > 1) {
                    return feature.cluster.length;
                }
            }
            return '';
        }
    }
});


layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: 30,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/db/ows?" +
                    "service=WFS" +
                    "&version=1.1.0" +
                    "&request=GetFeature" +
                    ..... +
                    "&outputFormat=application/json";

            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        }),
    }),
    // style: style_ch
    styleMap: new ol.style.Style({
        "default": style_ch,
        "select": {
            fillColor: "#8aeeef",
            strokeColor: "#32a8a9"
        }
    })
});
```

But it is simple cluster closed points and each state has more than one value according to the distance.

I want to show dot per every state on the basis of feature count of the vector layer. Here I got a problem that the styling doesn't apply and still due to distance property map show many points of cluster instead of one. I want my output result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: A picture of what you have now and what you would like to have would help in helping you. But anyway, it sounds like you don't want to have clusters but single markers that vary in size depending on some property.

Comment: yes so far i am having multiple points as cluster in one county. i want single point that vary in size depending on certain attribute

Comment: And which is this "certain attribute" and what would be the logic of setting size of marker on the basis of this attribute? Please edit your question and add that info.

Comment: @TomazicM i have added in the code var features = layer.getSource().getFeatures('no_of_literate');

Comment: I admit that having look at your code I have no idea what your data structure is. Please edit your question and add info about: 1. What a single feature represents? 2. Is `no_of_literate` property of each feature? 3. Is state single feature or composed of many features? 4. What are you trying to do with `layer.getSource().getFeatures('no_of_literate')`. Method `getFeatures` takes no arguments, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeatures?

Comment: @TomazicM i have edited my code and make it simple but still i did not get the desired result

Comment: point display on the basis of feature count

Comment: Feature count within what?

Comment: feature of vector layer var layer;

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand anything. I give up.

Comment: @TomazicM layer.getSource().getFeatures() contains point data of literate person. i want to make dot distribution map of these point.

Comment: I am stuck any help?